# How can I remap a stuck key to null?

Tags: macos, keybindings

I have a key that is stuck repeating and I want to disable it. Using KeyRemap4MacBook, what is the proper syntax for the `private.xml` to map a key to null?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the key to `KeyCode::VK_NONE`:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Z, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
```

See http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en or http://lri.me/keyremap4macbook.html for more information about using KeyRemap4MacBook.